# How to apply styles to <h:commandButton> from external CSS in jsf 2.0?

Tags: css, jsf-2, commandbutton

I am working in `JSF 2.0` application and using external stylesheets for UI styling. But I am unable to change the `<h:commandButton>` styling through external `CSS`.

The same was working with in-line styling. Also I am using `Richfaces 4.4` skin in my application.

Comment: Note: for today the latest stable RichFaces version is 4.3.6.Final. Are you sure you use version 4.4?

Answer (score 0):

For applying style in `h:commanButton` use `styleClass` attribute:

```
<h:commandButton value="someName" action="#{bean.method}" styleClass="yourStyle" />
```

Essential is set CSS **after** RichFaces styles (for example in template body, not in header):

```
<h:body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{properpath}/your.css" media="all" />
</h:body>
```

In my project it is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="#{request.contextPath}/css/basic.css" media="all" />
```

You can use `h:outputStylesheet` instead of `<link />`.